# Python 3.5.2 join on map objects, so weird

Tags: python, dictionary, join

[join on map object with Python 3.5.2 IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn8Rz.png)

Is join should not be used for map objects?

Is join should not be used for list created by map?

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> a = map(lambda x:x[1], [('11', '22'), ('22', '33'), ('33', '44')])
>>> list(a)
['22', '33', '44']
>>> '.'.join(a)
''
>>> ''.join(list(a))
''
>>> ''.join(['22', '33', '44'])
'223344'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `list(a)` *consumes* the items from the `map` object. So when you subsequently try to access those items again, e.g. with `'.'.join(a)` the `map` object is empty. That's why `join` returns an empty string.

You can call `join()` on a `map`:

```
>>> a = map(lambda x:x[1], [('11', '22'), ('22', '33'), ('33', '44')])
>>> '.'.join(a)
'22.33.44'
>>> '.'.join(a)
''
```

but once it's consumed that's it, so the second `join()` doesn't work as you might expect.

You can instead bind the result of `list(a)` to a variable and then use that again later:

```
>>> a = map(lambda x:x[1], [('11', '22'), ('22', '33'), ('33', '44')])
>>> l = list(a)
['22', '33', '44']
>>> '.'.join(l)
'22.33.44'
```